# IDE fatal error in Android Studio 2.0 while adding any .xml file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

Whenever i try to add a new .xml file in the layout folder in Android Studio 2.0, I get this error.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnIs9.png)

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.NewAndroidComponentAction.actionPerformed(NewAndroidComponentAction.java:135)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:311)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:281)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:109)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

When i try to add any .xml file in the layout folder i shows this error and i cant get a way to remove this.Since i am new to android development so i dont know much about it.Any kind of help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: can u tell me the steps u r using to make an xml file

Comment: Rightclick on layout folder->Add new file->Others->Android XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these go to layout-new- xml-layoutXMLfile or new -layoutresourcefile (then type the name in small)

Comment: Cant perform these steps sir, it shows IDE fatal error Exception in Android Support Library. Please check the screenshot.Thankyou

Comment: cool bhai keep trying it took me 2 day to set android studio p:)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like android studio ide plugin error 
try to reinstall android support lib package from sdk manager

Comment: I already did that before posting this problem. I removed Android Support Library and Android Support Repository and reinstalled them but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

right click on layout folder-->new--->layout resource file

Answer (score 0):

Your xml layout file not contain any whitespaces, capital letter(even Single one) like

Myactivity.xml is wrong

you could try like

my_activity.xml instead

also make sure you add layout file by clicking on right click and then adding new file.

Comment: Yes, i know that sir, but i cant add any layout file. It shows IDE fatal error Exception in Android plugin support.

Comment: Ok Just DISABLE THE PLUGIN it says in your screen shot at the top of the dialog. so try disabling it. then try creating a new project and then add a new layout.